# find first blank input in form by name

Tags: javascript, input

I want to add focus to the first blank input in form "#reg" containing 100 inputs all named "Player_Name" and other inputs with different names.

```
<form id = "reg">
<div>
<input id = "P1' name = "Player_Name" />
<input id = "P1' name = "Player_Name" />  
<input id = "P2' name = "Player_Name" />
<input id = "P3' name = "Player_Name" />
</form>
```

## I also have an array of objects used frequently which stores the inputs above.
myArray =

```
[{"name":"Ahmed, Simon","uscf":"2022-02-28"},
{"name":"Beh, Ryan Paul",""uscf":"2021-11-30"}
]
```

I'm not even close to a solution:

```
form = document.getElementById('reg'); // grab the form
nameArray = form.Player_Name.value; // grab the values of PlayerName
console.log (nameArray);
//nameArray.sort(); // sort those values with the idea getting blank inputs to show first;
//alert (JSON.stringify(nameArray));
//nameArray = _.orderBy(nameArray, '??, 'asc'); // or use lowdash, but not needed.
```

Anybody have any solutions?

Comment: Perhaps `document.querySelector('input [value=""]').focus();`

Comment: Finding and focus has nothing to do with the object where values are stored.  I  would remove that from the question or ask another question related two that if there is one.

Answer (score 1):

Many ways to do it, but you basically need to loop over them and find the first one that has no value.

```js
var firstBlank = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[name="Player_Name"]'))
  .find(function(elem) {
    return elem.value === ""
  });
// var firstBlank = [...document.querySelectorAll('[name="Player_Name"]')].find(elem => elem.value === "");
if (firstBlank) {
  firstBlank.focus();
}
```

```html
<form id="reg">
  <input id="P1" name="Player_Name" value="111" />
  <input id="P2" name="Player_Name" />
  <input id="P3" name="Player_Name" />
</form>
```

Comment: Absolutely spot on. The bonus was the ES6 script. Thank you so much, @epascarello.